# How to restart bootstrap tour?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, add-on

When I click "End Tour" button I can't start bootstrap tour again. I searched all the [documentation](http://bootstraptour.com/api/), but I have not found a solution.

Comment: Just press `start the DEMO` again? What do you expect to happen when you click End Tour?

Comment: And you want it fixed with no code posted, just a link to the documentation? not likely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Chrome devtools, under the Resources tab, check Local Storage - you'll see a stored value that the tour has ended. You can delete this value and refresh the page. To prevent this value being stored, you can initiate your tour with:

```
storage: false
```

Answer (score 11):

Try tour.restart() as well.
I just asked a same question and it's solved now.

[Bootstrap tour needs to clear cache to work again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468409/bootstrap-tour-needs-to-clear-cache-to-work-again)